# : Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only while trying to use to_dict

Tags: python, pandas, prediction

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = "C:/Users/ashik swaroop/Desktop/anaconda/Gene Dataset/acancergenecensus.csv"
datacan = pd.read_csv(dataset)
datacan = datacan.fillna(0)
cols_to_retain = datacan[[ "Tumour_Types_Somatic","Tumour_Types_Germline","Mutation_Types","Tissue_Type"]]
cat_dict = datacan[ cols_to_retain ].to_dict( orient = 'records' )
```

getting an error after running this please help or give suggestion :

```
cat_dict = datacan[ cols_to_retain ].to_dict( orient = 'records' )
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-47-dde9a2c1af34>", line 1, in <module>
    cat_dict = datacan[ cols_to_retain ].to_dict( orient = 'records' )

  File "C:\Users\ashik swaroop\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2055, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_frame(key)

  File "C:\Users\ashik swaroop\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2130, in _getitem_frame
    raise ValueError('Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only')

ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change:

```
cols_to_retain = datacan[[ "Tumour_Types_Somatic","Tumour_Types_Germline","Mutation_Types","Tissue_Type"]]
cat_dict = datacan[ cols_to_retain ].to_dict( orient = 'records' )
```

to:

```
cols_to_retain = [ "Tumour_Types_Somatic","Tumour_Types_Germline","Mutation_Types","Tissue_Type"]
cat_dict = datacan[ cols_to_retain ].to_dict( orient = 'records' )
```

because if select by double `[]` is is called subset and return filtered `DataFrame`, not columns names.

Another possible solution is:

```
df = datacan[[ "Tumour_Types_Somatic","Tumour_Types_Germline","Mutation_Types","Tissue_Type"]]

cat_dict = df.to_dict( orient = 'records' )
```

Comment: I did it I created the account recently it did allow me to accept it just now Thank you.